# Add frequency column to data frame but also consolidate column

Tags: r, distance, frequency

I have a dataset which looks something like this

[image]

I want to add a column in r that shows the frequency of each Distance value, while still considering the Groups

Ie., I want to change my dataset so that for example like this

[image]

Just wondering what the best way to do this is

Comment: With `library(dplyr); count(your_data)`

Comment: If you need more help than that, please post an example with sample data as copy/pasteable text, not a picture of a table.

Answer (score 0):

dummy data:

```
df<-data.frame(Group1=c("a","b","c","d","a"),Group2=c("j","k","j","k","j"),Distance=c(20,5,9,10,20))

df<-df[sample(1:nrow(df), 30, replace = TRUE),]
```

data:

```
    Group1 Group2 Distance
      c      j        9
      c      j        9
      c      j        9
      b      k        5
      b      k        5
      a      j       20
      b      k        5
      c      j        9
      a      j       20
      a      j       20

df%>%group_by(Group1,Group2,Distance)%>%summarise(Frequency=n())
```

output:

```
  Group1 Group2 Distance Frequency
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>     <int>
1 a      j            20         3
2 b      k             5         3
3 c      j             9         4
```

Comment: Tried this but got the following error message: Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
Backtrace:
 1. df %>% group_by(Group 1, Group 2, Distance) %>% ...
 2. plyr::summarise(., Frequency = n())
 3. [ base::eval(...) ] with 1 more call
 5. dplyr::n()
 6. dplyr:::peek_mask("n")
 7. dplyr:::context_peek("mask", fun)

Comment: :((( 
try `dplyr::summarise()` hope it's helps. I will create dummy data to reproduce.
@timeywimey

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using tally():

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Group1 = c("a","b","c","d","a","a","a","a"), 
Group2 = c("J","J","J","K","K","J","K","J"), 
Distance = c(20,20,5,10,10,10,10,10)) 

output <- df %>%
  group_by(Group1, Group2, Distance) %>%
  tally()
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   Group1, Group2 [5]
  Group1 Group2 Distance     n
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl> <int>
1 a      J            10     2
2 a      J            20     1
3 a      K            10     2
4 b      J            20     1
5 c      J             5     1
6 d      K            10     1
```